# Get garbage value in file while downloading from ftp

Tags: java, file, csv, file-io, ftp

I tried to download csv file from ftp .
File is downloaded successfully but it gives me garbage value in that file.
Following is my code

```
String server = "client.in";
        int port = 21;
        String user = "user";
        String pass = "pwd";
        InputStream input=null;
        BufferedWriter out = null;
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {

            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

             FileOutputStream fos = null;

             String filename = "Test.csv";
             OutputStream data = (OutputStream) new FileOutputStream("Test/"+filename);

            ftpClient.retrieveFile(filename, data);

            data.close();
    }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

What is the solution ....
please help

Comment: Why do you have `catch(Exception e) {}`? That means that *if anything goes wrong, you won't know what happened*...

Comment: Also, why do you never close the output stream?

Comment: i closed output stream ..sorry didn't update in code..and also write exception in catch